# Nuxt asyncdata axios on refresh loses auth token

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am calling a get api that gets an array of mail data. It works fine on postman. When I use asyncdata method to get the array. It only works once if user refreshes the page I get 401 error. I pull token from cookies just fine. Normally on non asyncData I do this to set up the header

```
this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token);
        this.$axios.$post('upload/avatar',formData,{
          headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        }).then(res =>{

        }).catch(err => console.error(err));{

        }
      }
```

This works fine and has no issues

but my asnycData is like this

```
asyncData(context){
      //Cookie has to be read for async to work for now if user disables cookies breaks this page
       let token = Cookie.get('token');
      context.app.$axios.setHeader('Authorization',`Bearer ${token}`);

      return  context.app.$axios.$get('get/all/mail').then(mailData =>{
        console.log(context.app.$axios.defaults);

        let mailMap = [];
        //create array to load mail data in
        for(let key in mailData){
          mailMap.push({...mailData[key]});
        }

        return{
         mailArray:mailMap
        }
      }).catch(e =>console.error(e));
  }
```

I am trying to make a simple inbox page that can send , delete , and draft messages.

Comment: I redid the whole page. I do not have this issue , the real problem is why nuxt clears my auth token header?

Comment: I'm with a similar problem, when I reload the page, axios instance loses the Authorization header value. I'm using it with Vue. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to the fact that since `asyncData` is running from the server, it'll lose any browser cookies.

If you're using axios, the nuxt community has setup a [middleware](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template/blob/master/protected-ssr-api.md) module that can be used to automatically inject browser cookies into server requests.